# Creating a column with the mean value by group

Tags: python

I'm trying to create a new column which contains the mean (by group) of another column. When I check the output post running the step, all the values are all nan.

I've cross checked the data to check if there are any missing values or blanks etc. There doesn't to be any problem. I also did the calculations in excel to cross check the data and I could calculate the mean for each group.

`XXX["VAR_MEAN1"] = XXX.groupby(['KEY'])['Variable1'].mean()`

output i see after running the above code:

```
count   0.000
mean      nan
std       nan
min       nan
25%       nan
50%       nan
75%       nan
max       nan
```

Expected Results (from excel):

```
KEY,MEAN
8Y2657000J8Y5683000C,1217.311538
8Y4007200J8Y5395000B,636.1032999
```

[image: sampledata]

Comment: Run a `.info()` on your database. You are probably not working with numbers (`int64`, `float64`) but with strings or other objects of which the mean cannot be calculated.

Comment: I did check this bit; the columns are numbers & not strings

Comment: Can you provide some sample data?

Answer (score 0):

Try dropping null entries of your variable first:

```
XXX["VAR_MEAN1"] = (XXX
                      .dropna(subset=['Variable1'])
                      .groupby(['KEY'])['Variable1']
                      .mean()
                   )
```

Comment: I tried your suggestion; but it hasn't helped. The output:

count   0.000
mean      nan
std       nan
min       nan
25%       nan
50%       nan
75%       nan
max       nan
Name: ELEC_MEAN1, dtype: float64